# Why does setting scrollTop fail to set the correct position?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a long list of items in scrollable list. This list is being create with *ngFor in Angular 4. I am trying create a feature that scrolls to the correct position of the list when the user navigates back to the list from a detail view.

Most of this feature works fine. I am getting the offsetTop position from the list item, and then scrolling the parent to this position when the user returns.

**However, here's the problem** -> the scrollTop property of the parent element  is never accurate. Even after explicitly setting it.

I'm setting it in an Observable stream here:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){

    let facilitiesListPositionStream$ = Observable.combineLatest(this.facilities$, this.scrollPosition$);

    facilitiesListPositionStream$.subscribe((values)=>{
      console.log(values[1]);
      if(values[1] > 0){
        console.log(values[1]); **// Correct position value here**
        this.listContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = values[1];
        console.log(this.listContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop);**// Correct position value here**
      }else{
        this.listContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;
      }
    })
  }
```

But when I check the computed scrollTop value of the parent

```
listContainer
```

in Chrome DevTools, it's always wrong and I can see the incorrect scroll position of the screen, yet my console statement are telling me the it was set correctly.

Here's the computed Property: [image]

And here's the console logged from the code above: [image]

What makes this problem weird is that the farther I go down the list, the further the position is off. This makes me think there is problem with calculating the height of each element, but I check that as well, and it is accurate.

Just to be clear, **the problem accelerates with each row.** 
When I click on elements in the first row, calculating the position is correct. The second row, position is off by 22px. 
The third row is off by 66px. 
The 4th row is off by 110px etc...

So the problem is growing by 44PX with every row. I can't seem to figure that piece out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter issues like this I first try to see if it is a matter of timing. Does it work if you place the scrollTop command inside a setTimeout? Like this:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.listContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = values[1];
}, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I thought it might be this as well, but it ended up solving the issue this morning. It was a height rendering problem with each item in the list. The height property was returning the expected value in the browser dev tools, but was acting differently on the page. I'm still a little baffled about it, but I will added a solution once I get to the bottom of why...